# Asyncio Concurrent Structuring for API

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I'm rather new to Asyncio and concurrent programming in Python, get some of the concepts from web dev etc.

I'm trying to make an API class that subscribes to updates from the broker and processes them as they come in, without blocking this class -> then calls to other functions in the api, eg **submit_order** and **check_fills** in my mock example will still work without being blocked by the **subscribe_to_updates** method.

How would I structure this code so that I can call **subscribe_to_updates** and have it run as a non blocking coroutine, yet still allow the instantiated class to handle other method calls in real time sub as **submit_order** and **check_fills**?

Mock API below:

```
class Api:
    def __init__(self):
        self.updates = []
        self.external_api = object()
        self.details = dict()

    async def consume_updates(self):
        # Connect and subscribe to websocket stream api and handle live updates, save to class/db/etc
        while True:
            update = self.external_api.get_new_update()
            self.updates.append(update)

    def subscribe_to_updates(self):
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        loop.run_until_complete(self.consume_updates())

    async def send_order(self, security_code: str, buy: bool, quantity: int):
        # send a request to trade to the external api
        details = await self.external_api.send_order(security_code, buy, quantity)
        return details

    def submit_order(self, order_id: str, security_code: str, buy: bool, quantity: int):
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        details = loop.run_until_complete(self.send_order(security_code, buy, quantity))
        self.details[order_id] = details
        return details

    def check_fills(self, order_id):
        fills = []
        for row in self.updates:
            if 'is_fill' in row:
                fills.append(row)
        return fills


if __name__ == '__main__':
    api = Api()
    api.subscribe_to_updates()
    order_details = api.submit_order('1', 'ESU3', True, 2)
    time.sleep(10)
    api.check_fills(order_details['order_id'])
```

Running this as is would see the api blocked by subscribing to the update, I'm sure there is a basic way of thinking about this that I need help with

Comment: All of the functions that you want to run in parallel need to be declared async def and contain an await, so you can make them into asyncio tasks.  There should be a main function, also declared async, that is launched with asyncio.run().  Using loop.run_until_complete in multiple places is almost certainly the wrong approach.  For external_api you should use a package that is based on asyncio.